# Webpack / eslintrc - resolve files extensions

Tags: webpack, file-extension, resolve, eslintrc

I added this code to my `webpack` configuration:

```js
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss', '.json'],
    modules: [
        'node_modules'
    ]
},
```

And it doesn't work. I can't import files without defining their extensions. But when I added :

```js
"import/resolver": {
  "webpack": {
    "config": {
      "resolve": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".css", ".scss", ".json"]
      }
    }
  }
},
```

under `settings` in my `.eslintrc` file, resolving works. What is the difference? Why it doesn't work in webpack?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you webpack config and make sure you provide `APP_DIR` correctly by `path.resolve` :

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss', '.json'],
    modules: [APP_DIR, 'node_modules'],
    descriptionFiles: ["package.json"]
},
```

Let me know if the issue still persists